# change "E" button to ui button unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so here I made a script for my platformer game. This script allows the player to push and pull the box, when the raycast player touches the box then press down key "E" player will grab the box using joint2D and player will play animation while moving right n left.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.UIElements.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;

public class trigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerMovement1 move;
    [SerializeField] public LayerMask jumpableGround;

    private PlayerPush grab;
    public float distance = 1f;
    public LayerMask boxmask;

    [SerializeField]private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]private Rigidbody2D rb1, rb2;
    Vector2 direction = Vector2.right;
    public GameObject Blockbig2;
    private Collider2D coll;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb1 = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        move = GetComponent<PlayerMovement1>();
        grab = GetComponent<PlayerPush>();
    
       
    }
    public void Update ()
    {
        Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x, distance, boxmask);
       

        if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "block" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {

            move.enabled = false;
            grab.enabled = true;
            anim.SetBool("Push_idle", true);
            anim.SetBool("player_idle", false);
            Blockbig2.GetComponent<FixedJoint2D>().enabled = true;
            Blockbig2 = hit.collider.gameObject;
            Blockbig2.GetComponent<FixedJoint2D>().connectedBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb2.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
        } 
      

        else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
        {

            anim.SetBool("player_push", false);
            anim.SetBool("Push_idle", false);
            anim.SetBool("player_idle", true);
            Blockbig2.GetComponent<FixedJoint2D>().enabled = false;
            move.enabled = true;
            grab.enabled = false;
            rb2.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
        }
 
    }

void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x * distance);
        

    }
  

}
```

so how can i change this script to ui button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this simple way to solve this:

We first need to create 2 methods for us to check whether the button(UI) is pressed.

First, create a **bool** in your script that decides whether it is pressed:

```
public bool ButtonPressed = false;
```

Add the two **methods** where we will change the state of the button:

```
public void ButtonDown()
{
    ButtonPressed = true;
}
public void ButtonUp()
{
    ButtonPressed = false;
}
```

Next, head into Unity, and select the button UI you created.
Go to the inspector and add a new component called **Event Trigger**, and click on **Add New Event Type**.

Select **Pointer Down** and **Pointer Up**.
Then drag and drop the GameObject where your script is located to the GameObject input field. And as a function, select the methods that correspond to the event. (PointerDown with "YourScript".ButtonDown() and PointerUp with "YourScript".ButtonUp())
It should look similarly to this: [screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naM1f.png)

Next, go to your script and change the `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)` to `ButtonPressed == true` and
`Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E)` to `ButtonPressed == false`.